# Copy SQLite table including metadata

Tags: sqlite, metadata, insert-update, sql-insert

I wanted to add a constraint to an existing column in my `SQLite` database. However, I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969187/altering-sqlite-column-type-and-adding-pk-constraint) that it is not possible to do so.
I tried the solution from [How do I rename a column in a SQLite database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table#805508), but there seems to be missing the copying of all the metadata.

I pretty much want an exact copy of a given table, except for the new constraints.

How does the `INSERT` command look like to copy all the metadata, thus the indexes will increase correctly, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a heavy user of sqlite3, but you can use the command line to get the data and "create table" and "create index" commands. I am using the 'History' DB from the Google chrome browser which has a table called "visits". The 'mode insert' command says to provide output in a format that can be used to input this data. The '.schema visits' command says to show the 'create table' and 'create index' statements. The 'select..' statement gives you the data. The database I used doesn't seem to have any foreign key constraints, but they could very well be part of the 'create table' information if your DB has any.

```
sqlite3 History

.mode insert

.schema visits

select * from visits;
```