# Sqlalchemy; setting a primary key to a pre-existing db table (not using sqlite)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have pre-existing tables in a database that I would like to use the [automap pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#basic-use) on.

However, to be able to use this pattern you need to have primary keys set as shown in the docs (and tried myself; failed like [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#basic-use)).

**Is there any way in sqlalchemy to set a primary key to an already existing `id` column?** (Ideally from the `Users` object shown below).

Btw, I'm using **postgresql** (vs sqlite which [doesn't seem to allow setting a primary after a table has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969187/altering-sqlite-column-type-and-adding-pk-constraint)).

---

FYI

So far I have been able to successfully access data as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

metadata = MetaData(engine)
Users = Table('users', metadata, autoload=True)  

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
user_q = session.query(Users).filter(Users.c.id==1)
```

But this gives me a list where I need to access values with indexes. I want to set values by attribute (column) names for a given row like done typically in sqlalchemy (e.g. via a `user.first_name = "John"` syntax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a raw DDL statement. If the column `id` is already unique:

```
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
con.execute('alter table my_table add primary key(id)')
```

If `id` column is not unique, you have to drop it and recreate:

```
con.execute('alter table my_table drop id')
con.execute('alter table my_table add id serial primary key')
```

In Postgres adding a column in this way will automatically populate the column with consecutive numbers in subsequent rows.

Answer (score 3):

You could alter the underlying table as well and it would be the right thing to do in the long run, but if the values in `users.id` uniquely identify a row, [you can manually instruct SQLAlchemy to treat it as a primary key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key) by [explicitly partially specifying the class mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#specifying-classes-explicitly):

```
Base = automap_base()

class Users(Base)
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # Override id column, the type must match. Automap handles the rest.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)    

# Continue with the automapping. Will fill in the rest.
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

Comment: While I was hoping for a solution not using raw sql; I don't want to have to define the classes like this somewhere before usage (I know this is not the advised pattern on the long term). However, this answer is useful as this solution might work with sqlite as well.

Comment: If you want to avoid raw SQL in migrations, and have not had a look before, I'd recommend [alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/).